# Has Java ever been used in outer space?

Tags: java

In response to a question about examples of Java usages, I bumped across some articles where NASA used Java for ground control in a mission to Mars but I couldn't find out if it has ever been used outside of Earth. Do you know of any such instances?

Comment: I will take a wild guess and say "No".

Comment: If it was, that would explain the last shuttle crash

Comment: Well, I know that computer viruses have been found in outer space.  http://www.geekwithlaptop.com/astronauts-took-virus-infected-laptops-into-space

Comment: @Trying to fix: you are 50% correct :)
@Pierreten: I think Java has matured a lot for use in real-time systems, and with the strong typing, things like the Imperial/Metrix mixup in the Mars Climate Orbiter could have been avoided.
@Mechko - How proud those virus-creators would have felt.

Comment: @Pierreten: What do heat tiles coming off having to do with software?

Comment: Java on MARS http://java.about.com/b/2008/06/03/java-on-mars.htm (not literally outer space though)

Comment: @Pierreten
Must be why Google, Ebay, Amazon use it (Java) because it crashes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you will find a paper discussing the current state of using Java in space applications:

[REAL-TIME JAVA IN SPACE: POTENTIAL BENEFITS AND OPEN CHALLENGES](http://dsrg.mff.cuni.cz/publications/KaliberaProchazkaPizloDeckyVitekZulianello-RT_Java.pdf)

They say:

> In short time, it is unlikely that
>   with current Java implementations the
>   whole spacecraft on-board software
>   could be written in Java. However,
>   Java could be used as an isolation
>   platform for software that has not
>   been assigned the highest criticality,
>   while the critical code would still be
>   written in Ada or C.

Here one of the same authors reports on a successful test flight of an unmanned aerial vehicle (UAV) that uses Ovm (open source RTSJ (Real Time Specification for Java) implementation):

[A Real-time Java Virtual Machine for Avionics](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jv/pubs/rtas06.pdf)

Comment: That's a nice article on challenges faced in using RTSJ in space. A similar article dated 2004 was published for Project Golden Gate that was targeting Java for use in space missions, but haven't found anything beyond that - http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/37998/1/04-0051.pdf

Answer (score 6):

One fact often overlooked is that most space probes use older processors. They simply cannot run current commercial software. They are not fast enough or powerful enough. IC chips in space are exposed to high levels of cosmic rays. They energetic particles can destroy the small nanometer components on modern CPUs and other IC chips. To work reliably in space you either need specially designed ICs with redundant components, spend a lot on heavy shielding, or use older IC chips which have larger components that can take a hit from a cosmic ray without being destroyed.

Most of these older CPUs will run with a RTOS such as VxWorks and are either programed in assembler or using a language like C and still get decent performance.

Answer (score 2):

Probably on the documentation laptops they take up there on the Shuttle, at the very least.

Java is also mentioned here, which implies that there is at least Java code that can talk to some spacecraft, if not actually run on them: http://www.dtnrg.org/wiki/Code

Comment: I think this is the best bet for "Java in space" -- plenty of ordinary
Windows laptops have flown on Shuttle and ISS missions, so it's likely some Java processes were running (although perhaps not in a mission-critical capacity...)

Comment: i think so too. There are few projects like Project Golden Gate that are trying to use Java for mission-related tasks and that was way back in 2004. It may be an eternity in the computing world but definitely not in space exploration.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, the Ground Operations Center uses it for [3D Mapping and Planning](http://www.cnn.com/2004/TECH/space/01/16/space.mars.java.reut/index.html). A [comment on this forum claims the Mars Lander runs VxWorks.](http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/16918-mars-rover-controlled-java)

Edit: Confirmed by Wind River, the [Spirit and Opportunity run VxWorks RTOS.](http://www.windriver.com/news/press/pr.html?ID=82) No other references where Java has been explicitly used in Space.

Comment: Found this article (http://www.sun.com/aboutsun/media/features/mars.html) dated Jan 16 (no year) on sun.com which states that Java was used on the ground side for a command and control system called Maestro. Java was used to control the rover remotely but no instances of Java being onboard a rover.

Comment: Was going to post that myself until I saw it was already posted -  in fact you can even download (a cut-down version) of Maestro: lets you render the Rover's position within mosaics of Images and simulate giving commands sequences to a Rover.

Comment: thanks for the tip.. can't wait to download Maestro and play with it, as soon as their webpage becomes available, it's down right now - http://mars.telascience.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think I read a few years ago that some probe or satellite used Java as part of their analyzation equipment but I doubt that mission critical software will be developed in Java today.

However: With all the applications used by astronauts on their Laptops I wouldn't be surprised if there were applications written in Java. Maybe some locally installed webapp that is used as a bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak with any authority with respect to the software onboard spacecraft, but I can say definitively that Java is used by NASA (or its affiliates) to handle the data from the various missions. I recently worked at a laboratory for space physics, which handled data and telemetry for in-orbit spacecraft, and the development team (of which I was a part) worked almost exclusively in Java.